# contact sensor is not working in Gazebo8 ,Gazebo9 and Gazebo10

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

- In gazebo8 ,gazebo9 and gazebo10 (install from source), the contact atrribute in ContactSensor class is Not work. When I get a ContactSensor by `contacts =this->ContactSensor->Contacts()`,
  Then the results of `contacts.contact_size()`,`contacts.contact(0).position_size()` and other related values are all zero or empty.
- But method like `this->ContactSensor->IsActive()`, `this->ContactSensor->GetCollisionName(0)` , `this->ContactSensor->UpdateRate()` and `this->ContactSensor->Id()` is work.
  Why?
- By the way, gazebo4 and gazebo7 is OK.

---

Problem Solved.It was the name of the collision cause the problem.I had named my contact link in xacro file like this

```
  <link name="simple">
...
     <collision name="simple_collision">
...
  </link>
```

and use it like this

```
 <gazebo reference="simple">
...
      <contact>
        <collision>simple_collision</collision>
        <topic>/simple_contact</topic>
      </contact>
...
</gazebo>
```

It would Not work in this case. I should Not  add a `<collision name="simple_collision">` in xacro file. Just use `<collision>` in xacro file, it will gives you `linkname+_collision`automaticlly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18497/contact-sensor-is-not-working-in-gazebo8-,gazebo9-and-gazebo10/) by [longwoo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3628/longwoo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 27 on 2018-02-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-02-25**:
It would help if you shared some minimum example which someone can compile to reproduce the error

**Comment by [longwoo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3628/longwoo/) on 2018-02-26**:
Thank you. You really give me a good idea to debug my code. And I solved it by simplify the model into a box. And find that it was the name of collusion cause the problem.

**Comment by [Dougie DeRosa](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14381/dougie-derosa/) on 2019-09-25**:
Hey Thanks! Huge help - I was stuck on this for a little. Would you mind discussing a little bit how you figured this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If your contact sensor is attached to a link connected to another link via a fixed joint, then the problem could be related with a name change in how the merged collision volume is called:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/pull-requests/235/collision_blobs-for-sdf3-branch/activity#comment-11990222

Check the name of the collision you want to attach your sensor to by generating the SDF file from your Xacro, or check the collision properties directly from Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [mark_vision](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3878/mark_vision/) with karma: 106 on 2018-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longwoo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3628/longwoo/) on 2018-02-26**:
Thank you. It was the name of the collision cause the problem.

**Comment by [Dougie DeRosa](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14381/dougie-derosa/) on 2019-09-25**:
Correct, you can not use the contact sensor on a fixed joint UNLESS you use the  tag on said joint.